java processes and SpringBoot. Javascript and java communication. Error when starting spring boot server, address already in use
Im currently working on a java project, which handles the output from my
javascript scrappers, and creates statistics.
Im using springboot to establish a server, and created a javascript file to manage the posts received, and call a scrapper depending on the post it gets.(im fully aware i can just use java processes to call each bot individually when i need to, and take the output from inputStream, but i wanted to get my hands dirty with springboot and learn a couple things more)
For this to work, i had to create a "server" from js side, so java can send posts, but it obviously needs to be ran first(before java server) and instead of starting the js file manually myself(through terminal call), i wanted to use processbuilder in java so it calls the js file to start, then start the springboot server and send a post.
The problem is that i get an error message right after my Threshold.sleep(5000);, saying that the address from js server is already in use, when the springboot server starts. I have tried this without starting springboot, and i dont get this error message.
Here is the java method that puts all things together:
public void run_scrapper(String spec) throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException
{           
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
       processBuilder.command("node", "./lib/webs/BotController.js");
       processBuilder.inheritIO();

        Process p =   processBuilder.start();
        long pid=p.pid();
        System.out.println(pid);
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);


                BotController botController = context.getBean(BotController.class);
        
        
        if(spec=="whatever")
        { 
            
            String s=botController.executeBot("whatever");
            RawFileLoader rf = new RawFileLoader();
            send_toDb("toscan",rf.create_raw(s));
    
            
        }

                p.destroyForcibly();
        SpringApplication.exit(context, () -> 0);


}

I was expecting for the js server to start, sleep a couple seconds so it doesnt set-up with java server at the same time, start the java server and send a post.
Although after the java server starts i get this error message:
11956
BotController is listening on port 3000
20840
node:events:497
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1898:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1946:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:2044:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1925:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}

Node.js v20.14.0

It seems as if the ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class); call, tries to execute the js file again on its own(at least thats what i understand), it continues to do the tasks i want anyway, it is not causing any problems , but i really cant understand whats going on here.
I also used netstat -nba |FINDSTR "LISTEN" |FINDSTR "3000" in windows cmd to check if the js server is running before i run the java project, but it is fine.
**I have also checked tomcat, which runs on port 8080
I also came across the fact the js process never terminates in my java code, even though  i use p.destroyForcibly() UNLESS i make a server.close() call in my js file
(i manually checked via windows cmd again, executing the js file-->checking for localhost session on that port---->terminating the js execution---->checking the locahost session again, and it is terminated. So i assumed that this would also work using p.destroyForcibly(); in java) :
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const index= require('./index.js');
const scanner=require('./app.js');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;



async function call_index()
{
   let v;

    v=await index.main();
    
    while(v==undefined)
    {
        v=await index.main();
    }
   
    return v;
}




app.use(express.json());

app.post('/run-bot', async(req, res) => {
    const task = req.body.task;
    console.log('Received task:', task);

    
    let result;
    if (task === 'whatever') {
        result= await call_index();  
    } else {
        const array=task.split('\n');
        console.log(array);
        //result=await scanner.main(array);
        console.log(task);
    }

   
   
   
    res.send(result);
    server.close();
   
   
});

var server=app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`BotController is listening on port ${port}`);
});



I know for a fact that this is happening because:
a)i see that the terminal in java never terminates, and
b)i also use tasklist /fi "pid eq current_pid" in cmd after the scrapper is done and i get a running session
(I know for a fact my scrapper is done cause i get the output printed out)
**PS. i use  processBuilder.inheritIO(); due to my bot being interrupted while doing the tasks i wanted.
if i comment it out, it "stacks" after a console.log() call, and it never seems to continue.
I also used this function in my index js file, to make posts to java, like printing the current status of the bot:
async function sendLogToJava(logMessage) {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 5000); // 5 seconds timeout
    try {
            const response=  await fetch('http://localhost:8080/receiveBotLog', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ log: logMessage }),
            signal: controller.signal
        });
        clearTimeout(timeoutId); 
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending log to Java:', error);
    }
}

It works fine, but whether i use it or not, it still stacks unless i use the  processBuilder.inheritIO();
